# What are better terms to use than "middle class"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

There is no doubt that the term "middle class" is used quite differently in America (where about 80% of the population self-describe as "middle class") and in Britain where it carries a cultural understanding, George Orwell proving that it was possible to be a "middle-class" tramp (*Down and Out in Paris and London*).

And what about that component of the American population who fit the British description of "middle-class" - e.g. who read the New York Times or the Guardian on-line, drink tea with their little fingers extended, take holidays in Europe, aspire to Ivy League education, watch foreign films with sub-titles, and tune in to the public broadcasting networks?

What are they called?

And how is the French word *bourgeois* used? Is that of relevance?

Comment: In the US, "borgeois" is generally taken to mean people who are, or aspire to be, "upper middle class" -- drinking fancy wine, going to the opera, etc.  It's mildly pejorative in most uses.

Comment: @HotLicks In Britain where self-deprecation is a socially promoting quality, adopting status indicators of that kind can be seen as *nouveau riche* and little removed from true gentility. Hence Orwell, as a writer, adopted the life of a "down and out" but through his writing proved that ultimately, erudition and presentation were the securing features of bourgeois life.

Comment: I would describe the group you refer to as "upper-middle-class".  As you say, "middle class" in the USA refers to the majority of people, who own their own home for example.  Class in the UK is much more complicated. Even in the UK the middle-class has grown significantly, and what to call people who aren't middle class is actually a challenging problem nowadays.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sociologists do have a number of occupational categories - A,B,C1, C2, D etc. The people you are thinking of may be the famed C1 category (or was it C2?) - "Basildon man" , people, who Margaret Thatcher famously persuaded to vote Conservative in 1979.

Comment: I only ever hear "bourgeois" (or "bougie") used ironically in America except in the context of history.

Comment: Though this is ostensibly about what particular labels mean, I think this question is more about the sociological content of those labels. Maybe you should ask this on http://history.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Everyone thinking of themselves as "middle-class" is part of the core American egalitarian mythology.  It is part of a largely explicit rejection of the classism of British society, dating back to the [country's birth](http://www.thehistoryconnection.com/American-Revolution-1.html).  No one here (with a [few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Trump) [notable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warren_Buffett) [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jay-Z)) wants to think of themselves either as poor or as rich, despite the ever-increasing income gap, and the disappearance of the actual middle class.  Being middle class is associated with salt-of-the-earth authenticity, but as combined with pull-yourself-up-by-your-bootstraps industriousness.  Here, therefore, the poor are called "the lower middle-class," the rich are the "upper middle-class," and those who actually *are* middle class are called "solidly middle-class."

And what of those who "who read the New York Times or the Guardian on-line, drink tea with their little fingers extended, take holidays in Europe, aspire to Ivy League education, watch foreign films with sub-titles, and tune in to the public broadcasting networks"?  The current *term of art* is "[the liberal elite[s]](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/book-party/wp/2017/07/28/liberal-elites-dont-have-a-clue-about-the-white-working-class-so-says-a-liberal-elite-law-professor/?utm_term=.cb7cedd07f5f)," reflecting how this group has been successfully cast as the villains in a politicized culture war.

The French term *bourgeois* is almost never used, but, as mentioned by Amy and others, its AAVE (African-American Vernacular English) derivative "bougie" has recently entered mainstream American usage.  "Bougie" is a mildly disparaging slang term that mockingly describes people who put on fancy airs.   It was traditionally directed internally within the black community against those college-educated middle- and upper-class black Americans who were seen as overzealously adopting exaggeratedly affected mannerisms as a way of separating themselves from the larger black community.  As contrasted with the affirmative Britishism "posh," it demonstrates the deep distaste of Americans for visibly classist attitudes.

Comment: We can criticize people's choice to identify as middle class and recognize the absurdity of 80% identifying as such, but it makes sense if we consider what middle and upper class historically has meant. In Europe upper class would mean that one is propertied and wouldn't need to work for a living. That is very rare in the US.

Comment: Not saying you're making that critique but it is common

Comment: @Unrelated - It's a fair point, but it's also true that people of that level of wealth in the United States do exist, but are likely to still take on a job of some sort, due to the social expectation, even if their role is largely non-functional.

Comment: It is interesting that we often discuss income inequality as opposed to wealth inequality. Would you venture a guess at where percentage of people don't need to work in the US?

Comment: @Unrelated Are you honestly suggesting that one would be more likely to find people who do not need to work for a living in Europe than in America?

Comment: @WS2 Haha let's rewind four years. No, I don't and didn't think there are more people in Europe who don't need to work. I believe my point was that _historically_ landed classes existed in Europe in ways that they do not in America (or in Europe today). If those classes were less prevalent in the US in the 1800s, American understanding of class would be different

Answer (score 0):

I only have an answer to the second part of your question - the use of bourgeois. I frequently hear the shortened version of this, "bougie," and it is used to describe something that is making an effort to be fancy, in a somewhat sarcastic way. For example, if my friend and I walked into a trendy, upscale restaurant, I might say, semi-jokingly "well this place is quite bougie!"

Comment: Where do you hear "bougie"?  (I haven't heard it around here.) And how do you pronounce it?

Comment: @GEdgar Roughly, it's /ˈbuːʒi/, but it's slang that I've never heard emerge from anyone over the age of 40. Wiktionary suggests it's akin to a modern *uppity* in AAVE, i.e. affecting the manners of a higher social class or income level than justifiable. A person could be *bougie* for always wearing designer labels and patronizing expensive restaurants; a store could be *bougie* in being overpriced and attracting bougie people; but more gently, a *bougie* design might just be excessively frilly or formal, like the invitations to a bougie wedding.

Comment: @choster It's not something I've heard in Britain - but then we have our own word, which has been around for generations  - "posh". People wear "posh clothes", go to "posh restaurants", live in "posh houses", drive "posh cars", send their kids to "posh schools", take "posh holidays", have "posh relations", speak with "posh accents", listen to "posh music",  etc. Its origin is not understood, though there is a popular *faux* explanation.

Comment: @WS2 Port Outward Starboard Home is faux?  Say it isn't so!

Comment: @WS2 "Bougie" is one of many AAVE (African-American Vernacular English) terms have have recently migrated into mainstream American usage --thus it would tend to be well known by both younger and older black Americans, but only younger white Americans.  While (as far as I know) "posh" has a generally positive and aspirational connotation, "bougie" is mildly disparaging and negative, similar to *nouvelle riche*.  Check this link for an example of usage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pErcly3n6I

Comment: @WS2 - Here in the US Upper Midwest I occasionally hear "posh" (and everyone would pretty much understand what it means), but never "bougie".

Comment: @ab2 I'm afraid so. The OED says: *A popular explanation...is that the word is < the initial letters of the phrase port outward, starboard home, with reference to the more comfortable (because cooler) and more expensive side for accommodation on ships formerly travelling between Britain and India. It is often suggested that the Peninsular & Oriental Steam Navigation Company stamped tickets for such cabins on this route with the letters P.O.S.H...However, no evidence has been found for the existence of such tickets*. OED offers a couple of possible etymologies, one from Persian.